# Getting error while trying to load HDFS with tweeter data

Tags: html, hadoop, flume

I am getting below error even though I have given correct keys and token. 
   I am trying to load data from tweeter into HDFS....
    I have entered correct key and tokens(I canot share key and token here,but i assure that they are correct).
        Please help me in understanding:

> 15/06/29 21:39:53 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl:401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.

```
<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;          charset=utf-8"/>\n<title>Error 401            Unauthorized</title>
</head>
```

```
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing '/1/statuses/filter.json'. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre>
```

Comment: first step you probably need to do is show us what is producing this error.

Answer (score 0):

It was happening due to clock out of sync: 
It was solved when i ran the below command:

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```